# Add a custom category page in WordPress.org

Tags: categories, page-template

How do I add a page that displays posts from a specific category and style the page separately? I want to create a page for every category on the blog. Is it possible to do so without using a plugin? I am using a theme called Zephyr which uses Visual Composer. Link: https://themeforest.net/item/zephyr-material-design-theme/9865647

Comment: re: 'a page that displays posts from a specific category and style the page separately': consider to create category templates - https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to make your changes to your parent theme
   (Zephyr).
2. Add all your new categories (if you haven't already). You do that in your site's admin area, on the Categories page, under Posts. You will see each category has a slug you can modify.
3. For each of the category pages you want to modify:

   - Find the file inside the parent theme folder which your parent theme is using to display categories. This file is called "category.php," or if that doesn't exist then it's "archive.php." If neither of those exist, then use the file "index.php." **Edit:** See Andrii Shekhirev's more comprehensive answer for  specifics about the Zephyr theme, and the ways you can use its `archive.php` file + associated template file together to build your category page.
   - Make a copy of that file, and place it in your child theme folder.
   - Rename this file "category-slug.php" replacing "slug" with the slug for your category. You can find this slug listed in the category listing, under posts, in your site's admin area — it's the page where you added your new categories. (So if the category is 'Native Orchids' and the slug is 'native-orchids' then your new file will be named 'category-native-orchids.php'.)
   - Modify this file and/or add css to your child theme's style.css file to style this page.
   - Once you've got this working for one category, you can follow the same steps for the other categories.

Here is more information for you:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to create a separate archive page for each category, without using a plugin. You have three options in this case:

1. Creating a separate template file for each category, as described in InSight's answer
2. Adding conditional statements to a single category template file.
3. Using custom CSS without modifying template files based on the category IDs.

The desirability of each choice depends on how many categories you have, and how much customization is needed per category page, as compared to the base archive template. If the desired changes are just cosmetical (e.g. change colors, fonts, etc) then the third option might be the simplest one. If it's more than a couple categories AND you need some dynamically generated objects on the page (e.g. a category description or modified category title), the second strategy might be a more manageable alternative compared to the first one, since in that case you'd need to modify only a single file if you wanted to make any changes later on.

Since the one-file-per-category method has already been described (very well and in great detail) by InSight, I'll just give some more info on the second and third methods below:

**Method 2**, aka "one file to rule them all". I'll assume that you've already created a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and have all the categories ready in the "Categories" admin section. To the best of my knowledge, Zephyr does not have a dedicated `category.php` template; it uses an `archive.php` and loads another template file inside, namely `/framework/templates/archive.php`. You can thus either re-create the entire structure inside your child theme (`archive.php` in the root and `/framework/templates/archive.php`) or create a new template file inside the child theme folder called `category.php` and just copy the contents from the parent's `/framework/templates/archive.php`. Next, modify your new template file as needed, using [is_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) conditionals based on category IDs or slugs, e.g.

```
<?php 
if ( is_category( 'Category A' ) ) {
    <p>This is the text to describe category A</p>
} else if ( is_category( 'Category B' ) ) {
    <p>This is the text to describe category B</p>
} else {
    <p>This is some generic text to describe all other category pages</p>
}
?>
```

**Method 3**, aka "keep it simple". You can add styling to specific category pages by using CSS, either via a child theme or by using the native "Additional CSS" tab of the Customizer. Each category page is automatically given a class which contains the category ID, and you can use this to reference individual category pages in your CSS declarations, e.g. if you wanted to change the color of the title to red for category with ID XX: `.categogy-XX .l-titlebar-content h1 { color: #f00; }`

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response. I would like the URL to appear as http://www.blogname.com/category. What method should  I use? I dont really have any coding knowledge, should I hire a professional? I would like to be able to style the pages using Visual Composer which my theme uses. FYI, I am using the child theme.

Comment: Hey Ritwik, you can use a plugin like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-taxonomy-base-slug/) to remove the category base slug (if I understood you correctly, you want the category name to follow the home URL directly); I don't think you can edit archive pages with VIsual Composer - if you need that, you might consider creating custom pages using templates available in the theme as replacements for standard category pages (then you also don't need to worry about the slugs). In case you need something more complex, I'd suggest hiring a developer :)

Comment: Hello, Andrii! Thank you for your response once again. If I create custom pages, how do I display contents from a specific category in those pages? Also, can I hire a developer to edit the archive pages? What skills should I be looking for or how do I chose the right person for the job if I am looking at fiverr?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there's a specialized element in the Visual Composer (Post Loop?) that lets you build custom post collections - and it has taxonomy filters that can limit the results to specific categories or tags. Regarding the freelancer - it's too broad a question to give a specific answer to, I think, apart from "she needs to have experience with  developing for WordPress and know at least php and html" :)